# Автозапуск клиент серверного приложения

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер

Задача была такая: написать на c# клиент серверное приложение в котором клиент передает серверу имя своей машины, а сервер передает в ответ команду.

Вот код

Клиент

```
var client = new TcpClient("10.50.1.1", 33777);
using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream()))
using (var br = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream()))
{
    bw.Write(Environment.MachineName);
    string t = br.ReadString();       
}
```

сервер

```
var listener = new TcpListener(33777);
listener.Start();
while (true)
{
    var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream()))
    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream()))
    {
         Console.WriteLine(br.ReadString());
         bw.Write("Run");
    }
}
```

Так все работает, но компилятор ругается что метод "System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.TcpListener(int)" является устаревшим. Если знаете как сделать код без предупреждения подскажите.

Теперь я добавляю отдельно приложение проверяющее версию клиента  (обновляет если есть новее) и запускающее его. Приведу только код запуска клиента.

```
Process.Start(Klient.exe);
```

И тут начинается магия. Если мы запускаем клиента вручную он подключается к серверу, передает и получает данные. Если мы запускаем его через автообновление. Которое может просто внутри себя содержать только одну строку (в main методе)

```
Process.Start(Klient.exe);
```

Клиент отказывается соединятся с сервером.

Как это пофиксить?

Все запускается с наивысшими правами. В брандмауэре стоят в исключениях и клиент и сервер и еще отдельно порт на вход и на выход.

Comment: Чтобы не ругался TcpListener, сделай так IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[1];   var listener = new TcpListener(ip, 22222); И порт измени, макс значение порта вроде 65534, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @Sergey_73 А как тогда будет выглядеть код binaryWriter/Read? 'using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream()))' неработает

Comment: @polsok >>Все запускается с наивысшими правами<< Кроме прав, надо учесть ещё environment + аргументы командной строки. На всякий случай, задам глупый вопрос - клиент, который запускается командой Process.Start находится на стороне сервера? или на стороне клиента?

Comment: У меня все работает отлично. http://radikal.ru/big/dw2qux33n7au2

Comment: @Sergey_73 кстати, а почему именно [1], а не [0]?

Comment: @PashaPash потому что у меня ipv4 находится под вторым элементом, то есть [1], а под [0] находится ipv6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервер

```
//using System.Net

TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPADRESS, PORT);
TcpClient a = listen.AcceptTcpClient(); //Разрешение на подключение 
byte[] buffer = new byte[a.ReceiveBufferSize]; 
NetworkStream stream = a.GetStream();   //Считывание строчки которую отправил клиент
int data = stream.Read(buffer, 0, a.ReceiveBufferSize);
string mess = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, data);
```

Клиент

```
client = new TcpClient(IPADRESS, PORT);
NetworkStream n = client.GetStream();
byte[] mess = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Строка которую передает клиент серверу");
n.Write(mess, 0, mess.Length);
```

Напоминаю что Ip, и Port должны быть одинаковы.
 Удачи!